# Python win32 ShellExecute error 31: 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.'

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, printing, runtime-error, shellexecute

I have a python program where I try to send a document to a printer. It works fine in my machine with a local printer set as the default printer and connected with my laptop via USB. However, when I tried it with another computer with its default printer being in a network it doesn't work. The error I get is:

> pywintypes.error: (31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')

The piece of code is giving problems is the following one:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0,"print",doc_path,None,".",0)
```

I think the problem is because of the printer being connected using the network and not the USB, but it might be another thing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ShellExecute has useless error handling. Use ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: I couldn't find the ShellExecuteEx in the win32api module. However, I found the cause of the error: the computer didn't have a pdf reader and that was causing that error somehow (the file to print was a pdf). Installing Foxit reader in that computer fixed the problem.

Comment: You can post the findings from your comment as an answer and accept the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the cause of the error: the computer didn't have a pdf reader installed and that was causing that error (the file to print was a pdf).

Installing Foxit reader (and making it the default program to open pdfs) fixed the problem.

Comment: thank you Sir, saved a lots of time of troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error when executing a simple print() command but in a command window with utf-8 enabled via the following commands:

```
chcp 65001

set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

This caused the error; probably because the string python tried to print on the terminal was in a different encodign than utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply installing a pdf reader wasn't enough though, I had to make it the default program to open pdfs too to get it to work.

Comment: I edited my answer as I also did that when I solved the problem but it was not part of the answer. Thanks for sharing.